# Get hiddenfield value c# page load after set its value on client side Masterpage return Empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is the master page code:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<script>
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

        }
        function showPosition(position) {


        document.getElementById("Long").value =    position.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById("Lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="Long" name="Long" value=""   runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" id="Lat" name="Lat" value="" runat="server" />
</form>
</body>
```

Here is the server side page load code:

```
Context.Response.Write(((HtmlInputHidden)Page.Master.FindControl("Long")).Value)
```

I have inspected the dom elments after load and this is what i see:

```
  <input name="ctl00$Long" type="hidden" id="Long" value="34.7574951">
  <input name="ctl00$Lat" type="hidden" id="Lat" value="32.003683900000006">
```

But when T try to retrieve them as shown above (C# pageload) I get string empty.

Answer (score 1):

Server side executes first, then sends the resulting markup to the client, where any client side scripts run. Therefore, your idea of order of execution is wrong.

You will need use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) or some other technique such as [web sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) in this situation.

Comment: @shreesha You could do it via Postback, but that makes for a poor user experience. Better to learn a modern technique like AJAX or SignalR.